# xcodeでAppIconにアイコン画像を設定しているのに実機にアイコンが反映されない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

xcode7.3.1にて開発をしております。
AppIconのiPhoneApp7-9用にそれぞれ
・Icon-60@2x.png・・・120px x 120px
・Icon-60@3x.png・・・180px x 180px
の画像を登録しました。

この状態で、シミュレーターのiPhone6sで確認をすると、アイコンは正常に表示されております。
ただ、これを実機に転送して表示をさせた時に、何も設定されていない時の、白い網状のアイコンが表示されて、上記で設定しているアイコンが表示されません。

cleanしてからビルドをしたり、xcodeを再起動してみたり、iPhoneの実機自体を再起動してみたりもしたのですが、事象は変わらずに困っております。
アーカイブをして、オーガナイザーのiOS Appsのところにもアイコンは反映されていませんでした。

ただ、
・Targetsの右ペイン上部のプロジェクト名の左側のアイコン
・左ペインのProductsフォルダ下の、(プロジェクト名).appファイルのアイコン

この２つは、設定したアイコンが表示されておりました。

原因がわからず、どなたか解消法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「実機からアプリをアンインストールしてみる」「ビルドバージョンを上げてみる」等は試して見られましたでしょうか? 同じような事象に遭遇したことはあるのですが、確実にこれで解消すると言えるほどのものではないので、コメントにて。私の経験では「まだ一度もインストールしたことのないまっさらの実機」にインストールすると必ずうまくいったので、それでもダメなら異なる原因ということになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「実機からアプリをアンインストール」は何度もしてはおります。「ビルドバージョンを上げてみる」はしてみたのですが、解消はされませんでした。また、「一度もインストールした事のない実機」も試しましたが、これもダメでした。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。私が経験したのとは違う厄介な状態になっていたようですね。何かこうなっていたせいじゃないかと言う情報がわかりましたらお時間をとって情報を共有していただけると助かります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一つ思い当たるのは、別の他のプロジェクトファイルをコピーして、違うプロジェクトとして開発をしていました。その際、プロジェクト名が同じだったので、その辺りでアイコンファイルが違うパスを向いてしまった・・・と、想像ではあるのですが、気になる部分ではありました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

その後、画像を変えてみたりを試してみましたが、それでも駄目でした。

ただ、新規にプロジェクトを作成し、もとのファイルを新規作成したプロジェクトに持ってきたところ、正常にアイコンが表示されるようになりました。
お手数をおかけいたしました。